# Как в JS вставить разметку HTML с содержимым PHP

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('.msg_content').append('<div class="card to_card col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3" style="float: left; margin-right: 7px; position: absolute; right: 0px">\n' +
        '<p class="close" style="position: absolute; right: 20px; color: white; width: 3px">X</p>                ' +
        '<div class="card-header msg_head">\n' +
        '                    <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">\n' +
        '                        <div class="img_cont">\n' +
        '                            <img src="https://devilsworkshop.org/files/2013/01/enlarged-facebook-profile-picture.jpg" class="rounded-circle user_img">\n' +
        '                            <span class="online_icon"></span>\n' +
        '                        </div>\n' +
        '                        <div class="user_info">' +
        '                        <span id="to_user">' + $(this).find('span').text() + '</span>' +
        '                        <p>' + $(this).find('p').text() + '</p>' +
        '                        </div>\n' +
        '                    </div>\n' +
        '                </div>\n' +
        '                <div class="card-body to_msg_div">\n' +
        '                    <div class="to_msg justify-content-start mb-4">**<?php if ($fullData) { foreach ($fullData as $key => $items) { ?>**\n' +
        '                           <div class="img_cont_msg">\n' +
        '                              <img src="https://devilsworkshop.org/files/2013/01/enlarged-facebook-profile-picture.jpg" class=" img rounded-circle user_img_msg"><p id="name">**<?php echo $items[0]; ?>**</p>\n' +
        '                           </div>\n' +
        '                           <div class="msg_cotainer">**<?php echo $items[1];  ?>**\n' +
        '                              <span class="msg_time">**<?php echo $items[2] ?>**</span>\n' +
        '                           </div>\n' +
        '                        <?php  } } ?>' +
        '                    </div>\n' +
        '                </div>' +
        '                    <div class="input-group">\n' +
        '                        <textarea id="to_txt" type="text" name="to_text" class="form-control type_msg" placeholder="Type your message..."></textarea>\n' +
        '                        <div class="input-group-append">\n' +
        '                            <input id="to_btn" type="submit" class="input-group-text send_btn" name="to_send" value="Sends">\n' +
        '                        </div>\n' +
        '                    </div></div>');
```

Comment: Используйте Ajax

Comment: а без этого никак?

Comment: в .htaccess добавляю это AddType application/x-httpd-php .js
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .js

<FilesMatch "\.(js|php)$">
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>, но тогда даже элементы не создаются